# Search File from current directory in a .jar Java

Tags: java, file

I want to know how I can search a File on the System, but the File will be place in the same directory that the .jar.
Example:

MySearchProgram.jar (executable)
MyFile.txt

Both files(MySearchProgram.jar, MyFile.txt) will be place in the same directory:
/home/jfabian/Documents
I need to read that file, to do that i need to Find it and specified the MyFile.txt directory, the problem is that I want to do it, from a .jar executable.

I know how to find a file, specifying the root, with this algorithm provide by Oracle:
[Find.java][1]

Thanks you in advance

Comment: There is something wrong with the link for `Find.java`.

Comment: Please provide the code that you have so far

Answer (score 1):

To determine the directory where your JAR file file is located, use

```
Test.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath()
```

on any class that was loaded from the JAR file (`Test` in the example above).